# What is pixel-wise softmax loss?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, pytorch, image-segmentation, loss

what is the pixel-wise softmax loss? In my understanding, it's just a cross-entropy loss, but I didn't find the formula. Can someone help me? It's better to have the pytorch code.

Answer (score 2):

You can read [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#crossentropyloss) all about it (there's also a link to source code there).

As you already observed the "softmax loss" is basically a cross entropy loss which computation combines the softmax function and the loss for numerical stability and efficiency.
In your example, the loss is computed for a pixel-wise prediction so you have a per-pixel prediction, a per-pixel target and a per-pixel loss term.

Comment: So it's just a cross-entropy? I got a tensor with shape [batch, 8, h, w], and my target is [batch, 1, h, w], and the target values is range from 1 to 8. So I can calculate pixel-wise softmax loss directly using the formula **cross-entropy(got, target)**?